# Redefinition Error

Tags: c++

I am converting an MFC application for deadlock detection in to Simple console application.
During this process I found many errors saying like

error C2365: 'CmdLockMutex' : redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'

I am unable to remove this error.
Kindly if someone could help me in this regard.

Comment: Just a guess: your error is around the line 37. I can't say anything more accurate without seeing the code.

Comment: It might help us to help you if you posted some code.

Comment: post the code that causes the error

Comment: You might find an answer at http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/87286/Redefinition.aspx  :-)

Answer (score 7):

Ok 4 years later to OP here is your answer...

**The Problem:**
With unscoped enums, you can have this situation:

```
enum Suit { Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs, Spades };
enum Tools { Picks, Shovels, Spades, Hammers }; // error C2365: 'Spades' : 
                                                // redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
```

**The Solution:**

```
Scoped enums solve this problem:
enum class Suit { Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs, Spades };
enum class Tools { Picks, Shovels, Spades, Hammers };
```

**Source:** [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2dzy4k6e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Use of the keyword class or struct in the enum definition indicates
>   that each enum type is unique and not comparable to other enum types.
>   In addition to this advantage, you can also forward-declare them
>   without specifying an underlying type (as you do with unscoped enums
>   if you intend to forward-declare).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a header guard around your definition of `CmdLockMutex` (Add `#pragma once` at the top of its .h file.). Or rather you have a naming conflict.

Maybe you have something like this:

```
enum MyEnum { MyEnumVal1, MyEnumVal2 };

//....

class MyEnum
{

};
```

Comment: Saved my day. Visual Studios errors were so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I've had an issue like this where some code definitions were placed in a header file.  The header was included in two places, and so conflicted with itself.  My solution was to move them to their own cpp file.  You might be seeing something like this.

Another cause can be failing to use a #pragma once or wrap with the #ifndef technique in a header.

Comment: In the first case if include guards were present you'd have got a linker error not a compiler error; the header does not strictly conflict with itself in that case, but rather you get conflicting definitions in separate compilation units.  So since this is a compiler error, by bet is on the second (no include guards).  All good points though.

Comment: @Clifford - I agree. For me, the first part was a linker conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that you have prevously used the name `CmdLockMutex` - probably in an `enum`.  Search your code for all occurnces of "CmdLockMutex"